# AppEngine Standard + cloud tasks - max concurrent requests

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gunicorn

CloudTask queue never runs more than 10 tasks in parallel on a single instance of GAE Standard(B2). What is a reason of this limit?

**Additional info:**

I need to process hundreds of long running tasks (which are I/O bound - using 3rd service API).

These tasks are served from CloudTask queue.

**queue.yaml**

```
- name: slow-queue
  max_concurrent_requests: 40
  target: slow-instance
```

Currently, I am running a single app engine flex instance with gevent worker.
It works fine, but I don't like the long deployment times ~10min.

I would like to switch from flex to standard backend instance. Because of:

- Faster deployment time (~2 min).
- Default cloud task timeout 24h standard backend instances ([link](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks))

```
The default deadline depends on the scaling type of the service: 10 minutes for standard apps with automatic scaling, 24 hours for standard apps with manual and basic scaling, and 60 minutes for flex apps.
```

**app.yaml**

```
service: slow-instance
runtime: python37
instance_class: B2

entrypoint: gunicorn main:app --workers 2 --threads 15

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

No matter how many threads I define in gunicorn, the cloud task queue never runs more than 10 tasks in parallel. I cannot find why is it so.

**My guess**

- GAE Standard is a single thread only - but why would it run 10 requests and not 2 (number of workers)?
- 10 requests is default value of max_concurrent_requests ([link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref)) (but that's automatic scaling, not manual)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting only 10 requests is because you are using manual scaling. Currently, max_concurrent_requests is only available using [automatic_scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements).

If you need the 24 hours time for HTTP requests, maybe if you [open](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases) a Support Case with GCP you could change the max_concurrent_requests.